# Are the Scientological themes in FF: The Spirits Within intentional or just a coincidence?

Tags: inspiration, final-fantasy

If you know the basic idea behind Scientology, it's hard to watch [FF: The Spirits Within](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0173840/) without being reminded of it.

Basically, the ghosts of aliens land on Earth and *infect* us with their ghostliness. (That's the movie's plot and also an actual religion.)

The movie's Wikipedia talk page even has a section titled "[Scientological themes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AFinal_Fantasy%3A_The_Spirits_Within#Scientological_themes)":

> I think it's noteworthy to mention that the story of the movie is almost a retelling of Hubbards OT3 material.
>
> Movie plot: A war on an alien planet causes alien spirits to land on earth (against their will). They posesses humans and feed on them.
>
> OT3: A war on alien planets causes that alien spirits come to earth (against their will). They possess humans, doing harm.
>
> In both versions, the alien "ghosts" were forcefully "ghostified", and were beings of ordinary flesh before. In both versions the spirits/body thetans are doing harm not because of evil intent, but because they are "confused".

From a strictly sci-fi point of view, it's a cool idea, I guess. Ghosts + aliens + crazy infection wiping out mankind.

But is this more than a coincidence? Did those wonderful Scientology people have anything to do with the movie?

Comment: **RPGamer:** *Where did you draw your inspiration from the story of Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within?* **[Sakaguchi:](http://rpgamer.com/news/Q4-2001/101401a.html)** *Actually, the idea for the story has been growing for ten years or so. The initial inspiration was the passing of my mother around that time. Since then I have had this idea and been thinking about it a lot.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AFinal_Fantasy%3A_The_Spirits_Within#Scientological_themes

Comment: They don't seem to possess humans, they seem to consume their energy.  Though there do seem to be other parallels there.

Comment: The way that "alien spirits come to earth (against their will)", and the reason it happens, seem to me to be quite different in the two stories. I don't think these stories have as many parallels as the simplified summaries suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the film's creator, the idea was to portray *spirits* as a vital ***energy force*** (one that could transcend death in a very real and measurable way) rather than a religious and supernatural force.

> **Q.** *Could you explain the religious principles behind "Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within" - the idea of the Spirits?*
>
> **Hironobu Sakaguchi:** ***It's not a religious idea, but we are looking at spirits - an energy force.** There is a conflict in the movie between
> people who see the energy as just that, and those who see the energy
> as a spirit. When my mother passed away, I began thinking about this
> and that's where the idea originated. There is action, as well as a
> love story, but if the audience can pick up on these philosophical
> elements, then that's a good thing.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Hironobu Sakaguchi - Final Fantasty: The Spirits Within: BBC Interview](http://www.bbc.co.uk/films/2001/08/01/hironobu_sakaguchi_final_fantasy_2001_interview.shtml)</sup></sub>

While this idea does (at least superficially) align with certain Scientological beliefs, Sakaguchi himself has said in a number of interviews that he himself is an atheist.

> **Q.** *Are you religious?*
>
> **Sakaguchi:** *No.*
>
> <sub><sup>[59 Developers, 20 Questions – 1985 Interview Special - BEEP! Magazine.](http://shmuplations.com/20questions1985/)</sup></sub>